# Select row by number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, row-number

I want to select all fields from a row of a table matching a particular row number.   This sounds simple, but I can't figure out the syntax from the online doc.  (I don't want to count rows or use variables to count the roles myself).  Something like this should work:

```
select * from mytable where row_number()=2
```

The simplest examples I can find (eg: [enter link description here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)) use OVER clause, so I tried something like:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY REFNUM
    ) *
FROM 
    MYTABLE
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER() =2
```

But still not valid syntax.

Comment: What version of Mysqlß

Comment: Isn't this the same as `LIMIT 2, 1`?

Comment: @Barmar: I think LIMIT X,1 will give me row X, but I was concerned that this would be ineffecient if it selects ALL rows, and returns only 1.  My hope was that WHERE ROW_NUMBER()=X would reduce the result set.  But I could be wrong, and perhaps they are identical

Comment: Unless there's an index on `REFNUM` it will have to read all rows to do the ordering. If there's an index, `LIMIT` will make use of it just like `ROW_NUMBER()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign an alias to the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression, then test that.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REFNUM) AS row, *
FROM YourTable
HAVING row = 2
```

This is essentially the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY REFNUM
LIMIT 1, 1
```

`LIMIT` starts counting from `0`, while `ROW_NUMBER()` starts at `1`, so the offset in the `LIMIT` is 1 less.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve the same behavior is by using limit

> SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1, 1